# Can you help to prove this property?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $T : [0, 1]^2 → [0, 1]$. Consider
the following properties:

$T_1 : T(x, 1) = x$

$T_2 : T(x, y) = T (y, x) $

$T_3 : T(x, T (y, z)) = T(T (x, y), z) $

$T_4 $: If  $x ≤ u  , y ≤ v \Rightarrow T(x, y) ≤ T(u, v) $

Function $T: [0, 1]^2 → [0, 1]$ that satisfies
$T_1 −T_4$ is T-norm.

consider $$T_L(x,y) = max(x+y-1,0)
$$
we can show that $T_L(x,y)$ is a T norm.

Conditions 1, 2 and 4 are obviously.
Can you help me to prove condition 3?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

\begin{align}
T_L(x,T_L(y,z))=\max\{x+T_L(y,z)-1,0\}&=\max\big\{x+\max\{y+z-1,0\}-1,0\big\}\\
&=\max\{x+y+z-2,x-1,0\}
\end{align}

Now, notice that $x-1\leq 0$, because $x\in[0,1]$. It follows that

$$T_L(x,T_L(y,z))=\max\{x+y+z-2,0\}$$

and similarly for $T_L(T_L(x,y),z)$.